# Obtener todos los tags de todos los posts de una determinada categoría

Tags: laravel

Necesito crear una consulta que obtenga **todas** las tags de **todos** los posts de una determinada categoría.

La relación entre post y tags es muchos a muchos a través de una tabla pivote polimórfica. La relacion entre post y categorias es 1 a muchos con tabla pivote.

Adjunto modelos, relaciones, migraciones

POST MODEL

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
  
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
   
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }

    public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
        }

}
```

TAG MODEL

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    //
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

CATEGORY MODEL

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function posts()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
     }
```

TAG MIGRATION

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

TAGGABLE MIGRATION

```
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->bigInteger('tag_id')->unsigned();
                $table->morphs('taggable');
    
                $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
            });
        }
```

POST MIGRATION

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
          
            $table->string('slug')->unique();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
           

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

CATEGORIES MIGRATION

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug');

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

PIVOT TABLE CATEGORY_POST

```
Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

He probado de traerlo con 2 consultas:
1º obtengo todos los posts de esa categoria:

```
 $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($query) {
        $query->whereIn('category_id', [$this->categoriaTags]);
})->get();
```

Esto esta OK, me devuelve una colección de todos los posts de esa categoría.
Ahora necesito **todos** los tags de **todos** esos posts.

Y aquí es donde me pierdo...
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Creo que si quieres todos los tags de todos los posts. Yo haría `Tag::has('posts')->get();` Esa relación debería traerte todos los **tags** que contengan **posts**

Comment: Solo agrega el `has('tags')`, asi: `$posts = Post::has('tags')->whereHas......`

Comment: @gaidyjg seria `Post::has('tags')` ya que el OP quiere "Todos los tags **de** todos los posts"

Comment: Esto: *la relacion entre post y categorias es 1 a muchos con tabla pivote* no puede ser así, creo que si hablamos de una *tabla intermedia* entonces la relación es también ahi muchos a muchos

Comment: Esa relación, posts -> tags te traerá los posts que tengan algún tag. Y no me parece que sea eso lo que pide. Dice que necesita todos los tags de los posts. Haciendo tags -> posts, te traerá los tags que estén en algún posts y bueno, eso es lo que pide.

Comment: Ya que quieres los Tags, empiezaría la consulta desde ese modelo, y la condicionaría checkando la existencia de la relación `posts` y anidada `categories`. Algo así `Tag::whereHas('posts', function($query) { $query->whereHas('categories', function($query) { //... }); })->get()`.